# load json using python

Tags: python, json

hello guys i am studying a python course and i have an assignment to read data from json file
but it keeps getting error

it keeps printing decode failed and no json data is loaded

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
import json

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Phani.html'

try:
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
    info = json.loads(data)
    info = info['contacts']
except ValueError:
    print('decode failed')
```

THE ERROR

```
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The URL you trying to JSON decode doesn't include any JSON content

Comment: You are probably trying to parse a HTML page using a json parser.

Comment: Your link is wrong... note 'html' in URL....  looked at parent link and see there is a JSON link: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json

Comment: thanks u guys so much :)